# "block_name" not found

Tags: theming, blocks, 9

I installed the Twig Tweak module.

```
{{ drupal_block('block_name') }}
```

doesn't work. In Drupal logs I get the error

> The "block_name" was not found

"block_name" I get from the config url of the block config page

```
admin/structure/block/manage/block_name?destination=/de/admin/structure/block
```

Do I do anything wrong?

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use:

```
{{ drupal_entity('block', 'MY_BLOCK_ID') }}
```

The [Rendering blocks with Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/node/2964457) guide walks through the three common block types and how to render them.

[Block plugins](https://www.drupal.org/node/2964457#block-plugin), i.e. custom blocks defined with an annotation

```
{{ drupal_block('MY_BLOCK_ID') }}
```

[Block configuration entities](https://www.drupal.org/node/2964457#block-configuration-entity), i.e. blocks configured at */admin/structure/block* (what it looks like you're trying to do)

```
{{ drupal_entity('block', 'MY_BLOCK_ID') }}
```

[Block content entities](https://www.drupal.org/node/2964457#block-content-entity), i.e. blocks managed at */admin/structure/block/block-content*

```
{{ drupal_entity('block_content', 'MY_BLOCK_ID') }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to place the block in Block Layout. Twig Tweak creates a block instance on the fly.

Use the block plugin ID. You find the ID in the annotations of the plugin class. For example the core branding block:

```
* @Block(
 *   id = "system_branding_block",
```

If the block is derived from block content the UUID is added after a colon, for example: `block_content:4124d2132-5ed1-4a12-add1-144e210da157`

More info https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/blocks.md#block-plugin